# Are there any goodies for SCJP?

Tags: java, sun, scjp

Just want to know whether SUN is providing any goodies (either free or paid), which can be availed for SCJPs ?? I heard like Microsoft is providing such goodies. Anybody has any idea on this?

Cheers,
PK

Comment: Microsoft provides goodies for SCJPs? That sounds unlikely ;)

Comment: Nothing from Sun last time I checked..

Comment: i mean MS giving to MCP or MCAD like that... :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get to put it on your resume.  That's mostly it.

It surely can't hurt, and it will look better than having no certifications.  Additionally, since they are administered through Prometric testing centers, it does stand as a verification that you do know about programming in Java.

I've seen so many resumes from people trying to 'hack' into programming jobs without any real programming experience (i.e. people with general IT degrees, former service-desk roles, other solely non-programming experience).  They often see benefits given to programmers b/c the demand is great, but the supply is short, and given their lack of knowledge of the area, they often assume they can fudge into such a position.  Unfortunately, they are sometimes able to fool hiring managers.

In these cases, a SCJP certification would be very comforting to me, since good programmers can come from such backgrounds, and it would be a reaffirmation that the person does have the requisite knowledge being sought.

Answer (score 0):

http://scjptest.com/ try this out which has mock tests.

http://www.whizlabs.com/ for paid services.